# How to evaluate $z^3 \cot (z)$ over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I know I can't use Cauchy's Integral Theorem to conclude that this is equal to zero because the function isn't analytic at $z=0$. So:

\begin{equation}
\oint_C f(z)dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{4it}\cot(e^{it})dt
\end{equation}
But this integral seems impossible to evaluate manually. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the residue theorem?

Comment: Not yet really.